# ConEmu new tab ‘Run as user’ using special characters for password

Tags: passwords, conemu, runas

I'm a long time ConEmu user and I have several tasks to open new tab that Run As User.
recently one of the users got password changed and it's using special characters like '^', '%', e.g: 5tgb%T^YHN.
the new password doesn't catch. ConEmu prompt me to enter the password again each time.
I have tried to put escape char before each special character, e.g. %% or ^^, tried to double them e.g. %%, ^^ and tried to soround the whole password with "". all failed.
How do I pass the password to the task so ConEmu can interpret it right?

Comment: test 5tgb^%T^^YHN or '5tgb%T^YHN'

Comment: You have not shown what you have tried

Comment: SSTR - tried both, no luck.

Comment: Maximus - I tried many ways to pass the special characters:
doubling the char: 5tgb^%T^^YHN
escaping the char: 5tgb^%T^^YHN
soround by ' or ": "5tgb%T^YHN", '5tgb%T^YHN'
all failed...

Answer (score 0):

**Issue resolved:**
I had also '@' in my password which apparently considered as special character as well.
The way to do it is prefix each char with '^' (esc) character.
For example, password 5tgb%T^YHN@1 should be:
5tgb^%T^^YHN^@1.

Thanks